# Grep and awk use

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep, adb

i try one day but dont fixed. I dont know this method.

```
 content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts | grep "+9053158888" |   awk -F'[,,= ]' '{cmd="content delete --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/"$(NF-3);system(cmd)}'
```

but not finding

My string

```
Row: 9991 last_time_contacted=0, phonetic_name=NULL, custom_ringtone=NULL, contact_status_ts=NULL, pinned=0, photo_id=NULL, photo_file_id=NULL, contact_status_res_package=NULL, contact_chat_capability=NULL, contact_status_icon=NULL, display_name_alt=+90532555688, sort_key_alt=+90532555688, in_visible_group=1, starred=0, contact_status_label=NULL, phonebook_label=#, is_user_profile=0, has_phone_number=1, display_name_source=40, phonetic_name_style=0, send_to_voicemail=0, lookup=0r10070-24121C1814241820221C1A14.3789r10071-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10072-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10073-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10074-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10075-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10078-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10082-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10083-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10084-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10085-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10086-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10087-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10092-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10094-24121C1814241820221C1A14.0r10097-24121C1814241820221C1A14, phonebook_label_alt=#, contact_last_updated_timestamp=1612984348874, photo_uri=NULL, phonebook_bucket=213, contact_status=NULL, display_name=+90532555688, sort_key=+90532555688, photo_thumb_uri=NULL, contact_presence=NULL, in_default_directory=1, times_contacted=0, _id=10097, name_raw_contact_id=10070, phonebook_bucket_alt=213
```

i need string " **_id=10097** "

Comment: Please show output of  `content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `grep` to find word `_id` followed by a `=` and 1+ digits:

```sh
... | grep -Eo '\b_id=[0-9]+'
_id=10097
```

Comment: thank you this is work grep -Eo '_id=[0-9]+' please awk because i need for this id like this {cmd="content delete --uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/"$2;system(cmd)}

Answer (score 1):

To get all occurrences of if try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `grep`. Where `str` is your shell variable have your shown sample input in it.

```
echo "$str" | grep -oP ', \K_id=\d+'
```

OR try with `awk`:

```
echo "$str" | 
awk 'match($0,/, _id=[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)}'
```

Above will output as:

```
_id=10097
```